# what are E[ln(1+x)] and O[ln(1+x)]?

Tags: calculus

Found this question in my old homework notes that I did not do at the time! I always wondered how I do this... The first part is a explanation. It is kind of long. Sorry! 
[image]

***Here is the actual question guys!****
[image]

Back then, I lost 20 points for not even doing this question :)
I appreciate the help!

Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I wasn't in your class, but here is my take: Determine the powerseries of $ln(1+x)$ and of $ln(1-x)$ and put them together. Then observe the even exponents and odd exponential terms to see what E(X) and O(X) would look like. I am sure this is where I would have ended, hoping to consolidate some points.

Answer (score 1):

So we know that

$$E(f(x)) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x)+f(-x))$$

and similarly for $O(f(x))$. These are just the even and odd pieces of the functions. Notice that $E(f(-x)) = E(f(x))$ and $O(f(-x)) = -O(f(x))$ so these really are even and odd, respectively. Splitting functions into even and odd parts can be *very* useful when tackling proofs. I've made heavy use of it in research at times. Let's compute them in your case.

$$E(\ln(1+x)) = \frac{1}{2}(\ln(1+x)+\ln(1-x))$$

This is simply from the definition. Now we want this in terms of one logarithm so we will do the following. Remember that $\ln(x)+\ln(y) = \ln(xy)$. Thus our previous expression becomes

$$E(\ln(1+x)) = \frac{1}{2}\ln((1+x)(1-x)) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(1-x^2).$$

We still have to do something about the $\frac{1}{2}$ out in front though. But recall hat $a\ln(x) = \ln(x^a)$. Thus we can rewrite the previous expression as

$$E(\ln(1+x)) = \ln((1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}) = \ln(\sqrt{1-x^2}).$$

Can you see how to do this for $O(\ln(1+x))$?